# Calling stored procedure with a string to use in query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a stored procedure where i need to pass a string to use in the query.

Stored procedure example:

```
BEGIN
SET @query = query;
SELECT * FROM test WHERE @query
END
```

How I would like to call it with a string:

```
CALL proceduretet('activity_id = 1 OR activity_id = 2')
```

The query can be different each time, sometimes there will be 1 activity_id and sometimes 4 or more.

I have tried to pass it as a varchar and text, but it won't work.

So is there a way to pass a string to stored procedures and use it in the query?

Regards, Andreas

Comment: If you want to have totally variable conditions, then you will need a `prepare` statement.  If you just want to limit the underlying SQL to one or two activities, you can readily do that with arguments for the activity ids.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I need to have total variable conditions, because the activity_id can bee different each time. By prepare statement do you mean I can't use stored procedure?

Comment: `prepare` is how MySQL runs a SQL statement stored in a string.  This is also called dynamic SQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html).  I don't know what the stored procedure does, but you can probably do what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I have tried to read the link you postet, but I'm not sure that I understand it. I have edited my question, maybe you can see if it is possible what i'am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would look like:

```
BEGIN
    SET @query = query;
    SET @sql = concat('SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ', @query);
    PREPARE stmt from @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END;
```